# How To Customize Existing Android Widgets

Tags: android, eclipse, widget

I'm asked to figure out how to give Android Widgets a custom look. The problem is, I can't seem to find a way to modify the look of already existing widgets in Android. Is there anyway to do this? Or do I need to create my own custom widgets to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't change the widget of other apps from your code.

Comment: I'm not trying to change the widget of a different app. I am creating an app and I want to change for example the look of a button in my app.

Comment: You can give custom look to any elements in Android. Please be specific and clear in your question.

Comment: Well I think I am being quitte clear with my question.. What I want for example is to edit the look of a button in the app that I am creating so I don't have the standard Android look.

Comment: Search in Google `custom button in Android` before asking. I can see hundreds of references to do this.

Comment: I have done that already and non of these results have actually helped me. You could also take my question serious and think of what I might be trying to achieve before referring elsewhere.

Comment: Then you have to show what are you trying to achieve. Blind questions won't bring any answers.

Answer (score 0):

Extend the existing widget and play with on draw.

```
public class MEditText extends AppCompatEditText {
private Paint backgroundPaint;
private static final int DEFAULT_SIZE = 200;
private static final int DEFAULT_FILL_COLOR = 0xffff0000;

public MEditText(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public MEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    backgroundPaint = new Paint();
    backgroundPaint.setColor(DEFAULT_FILL_COLOR);
    backgroundPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getHeight(), getHeight(), backgroundPaint);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

}

This will draw background color
for further deatil [Joshua Lamson realm Talk](https://academy.realm.io/posts/360-andev-2017-joshua-lamson-custom-drawing-canvas/)